# Compare BST date with UTC + 1 date

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a string date like : `2016-02-12 19:30:00`

This date is in `BST` timezone and I need to compare this date with today date. I am french so it's `UTC + 1`.

What's the solution ? If I add one hour to my BST date, it is correct ? Do I need to convert `BST to UTC + 1`, or `UTC + 1 to BST` ?

For now I retrieve today like : `$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`, and I compare my two dates like :

```
if(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($myBstDate)) >= $today)
```

For me it is wrong, there is an offset of one hour.

What's the correct way ? Thanks !

Comment: Always try to get everything into UTC, then work with it and convert back when needed.. Also what is wrong ? `$today` was defined at a different time than `$myBstDate` ? What is the expected result ?

Comment: Because for the date 2016-02-12 19:30:00 in BST, for me it's not 19:30:00 but 20:30:00

Comment: I suggest you stick to `gmdate` then, which will keep things in GMT for you.. Making life a bit easier. http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php Also don't be afraid to make use of the setTimeZone method : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score 0):

Legacy date functions are not particularly suitable for date math with time zone information. It's rather straightforward though if you use objects:

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-02-12 19:30:00 BST');
if ($date>=new DateTime) {
}
```